# Show ellipses for shortened chatroom descriptions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

For example, the Tavern on the chatroom list:

[image: Tavern]

The description is [actually longer:](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-of-fridayness-general)

> Here we have our fill of bread and
>   wine, and then tell of tales of other
>   times we've had our fill of bread and
>   wine.

Showing an ellipses would make it obvious that there's more.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree and would really like to do this, but since there's no way to know if and how much of the text is truncated until your browser actually renders it.

So this would have to be done client-side via JavaScript. I can think of a few solutions, but I don't know if any of them is feasible. But we'll think about it.

Also note that the full description is available via tooltip.

Comment: Also note that the same is true for room names, user names, and user "about" texts.

Comment: Thanks. "Also note that the full description is available via tooltip." Doesn't work for me in Firefox (in fact I thought about including that in my suggestion, but was going to post that as a separate one). What do you have to have to hover over for it to show?

Comment: @Simon I'm on mobile right now, so can't check -- I *thought* the tooltip was there; if it's not, *that's* an easy fix :)

Comment: @balpha: I'm pretty confident that you are very much aware of this, but I'll post it anyway, if only for other developers who aren't: JavaScript is not the only option. There's `text-overflow: ellipsis` for IE, `-o-text-overflow: ellipsis` for Opera and the `-moz-binding` workaround for Firefox. See e.g. [this question over at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893/determining-width-of-a-printed-string-by-a-webapp).

Comment: @RegDwight, @balpha - Safari also supports `text-overflow`; Firefox is [the only holdout](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312156). This SO question is also useful: [How can I mimic text-overflow: ellipsis in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820384/how-can-i-mimic-text-overflow-ellipsis-in-firefox). And of course, there's [a jQuery plugin](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/text-overflow/).

Comment: thanks @reg -- I was *hoping* that there's something, but didn't know any specifics, so thanks for the pointers!

Comment: and @simon, the tooltips are fixed now

Comment: @Dori *of course!*, there's a jQuery plugin :)